# CodeIgniter Message: mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection timed out giving error in server

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mysqli

I create a project in Codeigniter version 3.1.1. It's working fine on local. But when I upload it into the server then giving error:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user   'myprac_usr'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
>
> Filename: mysqli/mysqli_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 201

Backtrace:

> File: /var/www/html/myproject/application/controllers/User.php
>
> Line: 10
>
> Function: __construct
>
> File: /var/www/html/myproject/index.php
>
> Line: 315
>
> Function: require_once

```
$db['default'] = array(
'dsn'   => '',
'hostname' => 'hostip',
'username' => 'mydbusername',
'password' => 'mydbpassword',
'database' => 'mydbusername',
'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
'dbprefix' => '',
'pconnect' => FALSE,
'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
'cache_on' => FALSE,
'cachedir' => '',
'char_set' => 'utf8',
'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
'swap_pre' => '',
'encrypt' => FALSE,
'compress' => FALSE,
'stricton' => FALSE,
'failover' => array(),
'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

I have also changed the host name with "localhost" instead of host ip.

Mysql version- 5.6.27

PHP version- 5.5.36

Comment: Please make sure that database is on the same server and this user has access for the database.

Comment: The error is clear : user or password or host is wrong, or `$db['default']`is not used.

Comment: @Aniket Yes database is on another server but i am using for another project in zend it working great.

Answer (score 1):

Most Probably you have not provided the correct credentials for your database configuration.

Double check your username, password,hostname,

Answer (score 1):

1st one check remote server mysql port -

```
telnet 182.122.33.44 3306
```

If successfully connected it will print mysql version & others

then add mysql port on your CI code -

```
'hostname' => '182.122.33.44:3306',
```